# Hide Next Button until HTML video is not done playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lms

I recently launched an online tutor.

I need a function when someone done with watching video lesson next button should populate until that it should remain hidden.
Any help much appriciated
Here's the code I am trying:

```
const video = document.querySelector('video'); video.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {   const div = document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-single-course-content-next");   div.style.visibility = "visible";
});

<div class="tutor-single-course-content-next"> <a class="tutor-btn tutor-btn-secondary tutor-btn-sm" href="yield4learning.co.uk/courses/bank-guarantee/lesson/lesson-7"> <span class="tutor-mr-8">Next</span> <span class="tutor-icon-next" area-hidden="true"></span> </a> </div>

.tutor-single-course-content-next{ Visibility: hidden; }
```

I would like hide the Next button until video is not completed.

Comment: `const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  const div = document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-single-course-content-next");
  div.style.visibility = "visible";      
});`

Comment: Please edit your post and provide HTML and JS code inside.

Comment: <div class="tutor-single-course-content-next">
  <a class="tutor-btn tutor-btn-secondary tutor-btn-sm" href="https://yield4learning.co.uk/courses/bank-guarantee/lesson/lesson-7/">
   <span class="tutor-mr-8">Next</span>
   <span class="tutor-icon-next" area-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
 </div>

Comment: .tutor-single-course-content-next{
Visibility: hidden;
}

Comment: In message please, not in comments :)

Comment: guys.. my code is working now


var media = document.querySelector('video');
media.addEventListener("ended", BtnVisible);

   function BtnVisible(){

            var btnVisible = document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-single-course-content-next");
            btnVisible.style.visibility = "visible";

   };

But I am facing one error now: 
cannot set property of undefined (setting 'visibility')

Comment: Please let me know how can i fix this?

Comment: okie mission accomplished guys :)
I did it by my own :) yepiii

Comment: Here's the final code:

var media = document.querySelector('video');
media.addEventListener("ended", BtnVisible);

   function BtnVisible(){

            const btnVisible = document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-single-course-content-next");
      console.log(btnVisible);
             btnVisible[0].style.visibility = "visible";

   };

Answer (score 0):

can you use jQuery? if so, you can intercept the "ended" event and show up the next button like this width the jQuery show() function:

```
 $("#video-id").on("ended", function (e) { $(".tutor-single-course-content-next").show(); }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).